# How to configure CircleCi for running a JVM option?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jvm, circleci

**Context:**

I have a Maven (Spring Boot, Vaadin, MongoDB) Application and I had the problem that the default SSL protocol was wrong, so I added in IntelliJ IDEA under VM Options:

```
 -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

It worked fine.

**Problem:**

After that i tried to add this JVM argument to CircleCI (environment -> JAVA_OPTS) but i didn't work.

config.yml:

```
jobs:
      - maven/test
test:
maven/test:
  environment:
    # Configure the JVM and Gradle to avoid OOM errors
    _JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2"
```

So i tried to add a .mvn directory to my Project route and added a jvm.config file and also added the arg.

[jvm.config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y83cX.png)

config.yml

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  maven: circleci/maven@1.1

workflows:
  maven_test:
    jobs:
      - maven/test:
```

I don't know how to continue.
Can anyone help me?

My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>se-team1</artifactId>
    <name>Exemplar Management Tool</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>14.5.1</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->

        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Excluding so that webjars are not included. -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.artur</groupId>
            <artifactId>a-vaadin-helper</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Include JUnit 4 support for TestBench and others -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-elemental</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed
                     the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout.  -->
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>
                        -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2
                    </jvmArguments>
                    <wait>500</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--
                Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
                package.json and main.js files.
                It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Production -->
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: What does that means: `that the default SSL protocol was wrong` ? Which JDK do you use?

Comment: JDK-14, Errorcode: {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request}} The Solution: https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/sslhandshakeexception-should-not-be-presented-in-certificate-request/12493